# How do I merge two arrays with corresponding incremented keys in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a two arrays in php

```
$arr1 = array(1=>332, 2=>333, 3=>74, 4=>78);
$arr2 = array(1=>'heading1', 3=>'heading2');
```

**Note:Second array keys should not be changed.**

I need a output like below.

```
array(
    1 => 'heading1',
    2 => 332,
    3 => 'heading2',
    4 => 333,
    5 => 74,
    6 => 78
)
```

Please help

Answer (score 3):

This one gives the required output..

```
$arr1 = array(1=>332, 2=>333, 3=>74, 4=>78);
$arr2 = array(1=>'heading1', 3=>'heading2');
$arr3 = array();
$total = count($arr1) + count($arr2);
for($i=1; $i<= $total; $i++)
{
    if(isset($arr2[$i])) {
        $arr3[$i] = $arr2[$i];
        continue;
    }

    $arr3[$i] = array_shift($arr1);
}

print_r($arr3);
```

[Codepad link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vZDDIS)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working for me. I experienced 7 hours for find this solution.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Merge arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Have a look at that, see the examples on the page :)

Comment: As an ideea, SO wants to become a repository of knowledge. And it wants to become the first google search result for any software question. Hence a good answer on SO only refers to external documentation as an expansion to the answer you give. Otherwise SO becomes a link list.

Comment: Oh, then I'm gonna give code examples in the future. Point taken and understood!